# Can I redirect (on a client computer running ubuntu) a domain to a different address?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns

I need to test a site running at hosting.com/~myacct before pointing a domain to it. I'd like to fool my browser so when it points to testdomain.com it actually reads from  hosting.com/~myacct.

Can I do that without modifying the server, and without using a temporary domain? I can modify anything (hosts file, etc) on the machine running the browser.

Thanks for any assitance.

Comment: Modify the hosts file on the client, but the server must be aware, it's hosting that domain

Comment: I believe the hosts file can only point to a new address, but not to a specific account/path inside that address

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are entitled to change the html pages on testdomain.com,

In the  section of your html landing page, try adding this:

```
< meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://hosting.com/~myacct/" />
```